# "Not want to hurt" synonyms

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, academic-writing

I want to express that people act in a way that they do 'not want to hurt/harm' a company. However, I wonder if there is another way to express it without a reference to physical suffering. As people might suffer but organizations cannot.

Furthermore, I am wondering whether a sentence like 'He did not resign as he did not want to hurt/harm his employer' is good (academic) English or whether there are better ways to express this 'nice behavior'.

Comment: They do not want to damage the company, perhaps?

Comment: I would forget harm/hurt. He did  not want to cause any trouble/problems/issues for the company.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Lambie While I agree, I just wonder why this sounds wrong/colloquial

Comment: I would not use those since harm/hurt are things you cause to people, usually. Unless you use harm in the legal sense. It's over-reading what a company is.

Comment: “Harm” is idiomatic in this context and is particularly used in a legal and business context to refer to companies and other firms. For example, “...any breach of a statutory obligation which causes harm to the company...” https://hjsolicitors.co.uk/article/directors-duties-liabilities-and-responsibilities-of-a-company-directorship/

Comment: There are of course many synonyms possible for “harm”. Which will work for you will depend on context because synonyms often carry with them other shades of meaning. For example: “...he did not want to disadvantage his employer.” might work if disadvantage is the sort of harm you mean.